# The method is there but it does not work like it's supposed to

Tags: java

I have the following code -in Java btw-  and it compiles fine but when I input invalid parameters it doesn't recognize them as errors and accepts them as if they met the conditions.The method that concerns me is SetMPG(int average) . It's my first time here so I apologize if my question is vague I would fill in more information if necessary.

```
public class Vehicle {
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int tireCount;
    private int mPG;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Vehicle
     */
    public Vehicle(int tCount, int mP) {
        // initialise instance variables
        tireCount = tCount;
        mPG = mP;
    }


    public void setTire(int tire) {
        if (tire >= 0) {
            tireCount = tire;

        } else/*if( tire < 0)*/ {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Values must be positive");
        }

    }

    public void setMPG(int average) {
        if (average > 0) {
            mPG = average;
        } else if (average < 0) {

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Values must be positive");
        }

    }

    public int getTire() {
        return tireCount;
    }

    public int getMPG() {
        return mPG;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("There are " + tireCount + " tires and an average of " + mPG + "mpg");
    }

public class VehicleTest
{
// instance variables - replace the example below with your own
public static void main(String []args)
{
    Vehicle bike = new Vehicle( 2,-23); // first parameter is for tires , second is for   MPG
   System.out.println(bike);

}
}
```

Comment: How are you inputting the invalid parameters?

Comment: In the driver class i use instances with negative values . E.G : -32 , -9 , -11 and so on.

Comment: Are you sure it compiles correctly? You have syntax errors everywhere in this code block.

Comment: I think that what you've called "the driver class" is what you need to be showing us.

Comment: yes it compiles correctly but when I execute it , it appears as if the method was non-existent at all. But I might not see it clearly , so could you tell me what exactly of all the block is wrong? And also thanks for the help in advance guys!

Comment: @DavidWallace  right! I'll upload it shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code and what you're saying, It is most likely that you are setting your parameters via the constructor. Change your constructor to be of the form:

```
public  Vehicle(int tCount , int mP)
{
    // initialise instance variables
    setTire(tCount);
    setMPG(mP);
}
```

Also not sure whether 0 is a valid value for mpg???

```
public  void  setMPG(int average)
{
     if( average > 0) //should it be >= 0???
     {
        mPG=average;
     }
     else if(average < 0) // should it be  <=0 ????
     {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Values must be positive");
     }
}
```

Comment: That did indeed work and solve my problem , thanks everyone for   it. I ask this because I'm self studying this @ home but is it possible that instead of it saying the "java.lang..." it just displays the message "Values must be positive" ? or should I use a try and catch block for that?

Comment: There are different ways to approach it, but probably the easiest way for now is to introduce a try/catch block in your VehicleTest to catch the exception and print the message.